# Intellij android studio (Flutter) code completion suggestions are not sorted properly

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea

I have an annoying problem,  Code Completion in Flutter (Dart) suggestions are not sorted properly , when i start to type, suggestions sorted are not order then expected, i have to type all the words to get the relevant suggestion, you can see in the picture. This problem occurs all of the suggestions.

Expected result (I was following a training online): [.push comes up in the first place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ykh.png)

In my situation:
[.push is in the 10th place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haWeD.png)

I search and the internet but couldn't find a solution, i try to reinstall flutter and dart plugin. Invalidate cache but no luck. Please help me to solve this annoying problem.